# Symfony 5 NormalizerInterface not found

Tags: php, symfony, visual-studio-code

i'm following a tutorial online on how to use Symfony

i followed all the step but for some reason when is try to use NormalizeInterface i get this **error** :

*Cannot determine controller argument for "App\Controller\ApiPostController::index()": the $normalizer argument is type-hinted with the non-existent class or interface: "App\Controller\NormalizerInterface". Did you forget to add a use statement?*

I tried multiple solutions and none of them worked

My code is

```
 <?php

 namespace App\Controller;

 use App\Repository\PostRepository;
 use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;  
 use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;  
 use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Serializer;  
 use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer;  



class ApiPostController extends AbstractController   
{  
    /**  
     * @Route("/api/post", name="api_post_index", methods={"GET"})  
     */  
    public function index(PostRepository $postRepository, NormalizerInterface  $normalizer    )  
    {
      $posts = $postRepository->findAll();

      $postsNormalises = $normalizer->normalize($posts, null, ['groups' => 'post:read']);

        return $this->render('api_post/index.html.twig', [
            'controller_name' => 'ApiPostController',
        ]);
    }
}
```

Thank you for taking the time to read and thank you for you help in advance

Comment: You can try clearing the cache and you can see what "bin/console debug:container NormalizerInterface" yields.  It should be set to the serializer service by default but if your tutorial involves creating a different serializer then you will need a bit of tweaking.

Answer (score 0):

Add use line:

```
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\NormalizerInterface;
```

Comment: @Cerad It's easy when you read error message to the end :) `Did you forget to add a use statement?`